# for-loop for "fitting" a complex number

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I need to calculate something with the refractive index that looks like this ref_i=n+ik, so its a complex number. I then compare the result with my given data to compare them. But I have no clue how to test ALL possible complex number combinations in an effective way. Right now I'm only doing the real part:

```
n = 0.1
step = 0.001

for i in range (1,8000):
    calculation()
    compare()
    n = n + step
```

while n can be anything between 0.1 and 8, k can be 0-20. And there is no special connection between them, so every combination is allowed. Is there a clever way to get the complex number in there? Or do I have to calculate EVERY POSSIBLE combination of the two?

Comment: Use a list or tuple to represent a complex number. And use some so called precision to close to the value you need. I donot think you need to include all possible combinations.

Comment: So you're looking for an optimization routine (with complex numbers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `numpy.linspace` and `numpy.meshgrid`:

```
import numpy
lsp_re = numpy.linspace(0.1, 8, 8000)
lsp_im = numpy.linspace(0, 20, 20001)
re, im = numpy.meshgrid(lsp, lsp, copy=False)
matrix = 1j * im + re
for c in matrix.flat:
    dosomething(c)
```

However this way you have 8000 × 8000 = 64000000 combinations, so it may be more efficient to have less steps or use Monte Carlo algorithm, if you fear data may behave differently exactly where the steps happen.

By the way, if you want the points to be round numbers do not provide round numbers as ranges, but rather someting like *<some round number> + 1*:

```
>>> numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10)
array([  0.        ,   1.11111111,   2.22222222,   3.33333333,
         4.44444444,   5.55555556,   6.66666667,   7.77777778,
         8.88888889,  10.        ])
>>> numpy.linspace(0, 10, 11)
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.])
```

Comment: I made a typo, its 8000 steps for n. But it should be 20000 steps for i

Comment: Thanks, thats really helpful. But I think you mean the steps, not the ranges. And 0.1 cant be described perfrectly as a float, so i get strange numbers without np.round anyways